# Access $this from outside Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am playing around with the Mini Cart content from outside of Magento.

A section of code uses `$this`:

```
<?php foreach($cartItems as $_item): ?>
  <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

`get_class($this)` tells me that it is using `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar`

How can I access this?

For example I know you can replace `$this` with `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')`, is there an equivalent for `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar`?

Answer (score 2):

Try to create object of this class like below hope this helps.

```
<?php $obj = new Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar;?>
<?php foreach($cartItems as $_item): ?>
  <?php echo $obj->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
<?php $sidebarBlock = Mage::getBlockSingleton('checkout/cart_sidebar');
foreach($cartItems as $_item):
   echo $sidebarBlock->getItemHtml($_item);
 endforeach; ?>
```